# How to flag that an exception has been handled in bot code?

Tags: botframework

I have a root dialog that creates a child dialog like so...

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    string userName = context.Activity?.From.Name;

    var customerForm = new FormDialog<CarValuationDialog>(
        new CarValuationDialog(userName),
        () => CarValuationDialog.BuildForm(),
        FormOptions.PromptInStart);

    context.Call(customerForm, FormSubmitted);
}
```

The `FormSubmitted` method looks like....

```
public async Task FormSubmitted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<CarValuationDialog> result)
{
    try
    {
        var form = await result;

    }
    catch (FormCanceledException<CarValuationDialog> e)
    {
        string reply;
        if (e.InnerException == null)
        {
            reply = e.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            reply = e.InnerException.Message;
        }

        context.Reset();

        await context.PostAsync(reply);
    }
}
```

When an exception occurs in the child dialog, the method `FormSubmitted` is executed and goes into the catch block. However, when that method finishes, I still see the "Sorry my bot had an issue" type message appear to the user.

How can I tell the bot code not to fire the unhandled exception code, I believe is in `PostUnhandledExceptionToUser`? Is there a flag type property I need to set to true or something?

Comment: I think you got this error due to your `context.Reset();`. Can you add more details about your root dialog?

Comment: Turns out you are right. I thought I needed `context.Reset()` but that was causing the unhandled exception. Remove that call has worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you emptied the dialog stack so the bot don't know what to do. Here removing this cause the next message to continue to be handled by your root dialog

Comment: Could you move your comment into an answer please? That way I can accept it, just for closure purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are making the dialog stack empty when you have an exception: you should not have this `context.Reset()` below:

```
public async Task FormSubmitted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<CarValuationDialog> result)
{
    try
    {
        var form = await result;

    }
    catch (FormCanceledException<CarValuationDialog> e)
    {
        string reply;
        if (e.InnerException == null)
        {
            reply = e.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            reply = e.InnerException.Message;
        }

        context.Reset();

        await context.PostAsync(reply);
    }
}
```

Remove this line and the next message will be handled by your root dialog

Answer (score 2):

in your message controller in POST method, use defaultifexception

```
  await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.DialogLUIS().DefaultIfException());
```

Comment: In this case, removing the call to `context.Reset()` fixed the issue. Though I'm going to keep your answer in my notes, as the `DefaultIfException` method looks very useful.